# Add, remove or replace references in MS Access .mdb programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm working with a collection of `MS Access databases`. With the databases still as `.mdb` (i.e prior to compiling into .mde), I'm trying to update references using `C#`.

So, instead of opening each Access database separately, `Tools -> References -> Browse... etc.`, I want to iterate through selected databases and update the particular reference path to a new value specified in a `C#` application.

Looping through the databases is not a problem; I'm stuck at accessing the references.

Is this possible?

Comment: if you use Access Application instance you can use
application.References.Item(1).FullPath to read and .AddFromFile or .AddFromGuid to add new reference.

Comment: What reference do I need in my C# project to use Access Application?

Comment: Although I have the reference to the Interop.Access and the using directive `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` at the top of my class, I cannot access the Access.Application. 
Why? Please help..

BTW, I'm running VS2010 and Access 2010.

Comment: Please clarify what the exact problem "cannot access the Access.Application." is.

Comment: The only option that presents from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` is `Dao`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM reference you need for your C# project is "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library". That should enable you to do something like

```cs
accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
int numReferences = accessApp.References.Count;
```

Comment: Hadn't twigged the 'Accept' function; I'd just been upvoting the answers that had been helpful. I get it now, thanks for the heads-up and also for your help with this particular question.